# StrongLoop LoopBack change models layout

Tags: layout, models, loopbackjs, strongloop

does anyone knows if it is possible to change the layout of models folder in loopback? For instance:

test1: models/test1/test1.js or json

test2: models/test2/test2.js or json

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define any directory you want in `model-config.json` file.

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      " models/test1",
      " models/test2",
      ...
    ]
  ...
   }
}
```